# How to whitelist individual files through ClamTK's interface and NOT just entire directories

Tags: scanner, clamtk

Question is self explanatory. I don't want to whitelist a whole directory since new files could be inserted or placed there later and they would automatically get whitelisted. I only want to whitelist individual files, but in the ClamTK interface this does not seem possible.

Comment: Hey Clam has its own support at Online Forums located at http://forums.clamwin.com that may be more helpful then asking here.

Comment: Thanks, should I remove the question here then?

Comment: No others may benefit from it.